# bootstrap date picker setting date one day behind<Reactive Form /Angular 8>

Tags: angular

I use bootstrap date picker and able to save date correctly to backend using reactive form. However, fetching the same date to UI, date showed is always one day behind.

**CODE:**

```
 this.subjectPersonalform = this.formBuilder.group({dob_info: formBuilder.group({
    dob: null,
    dob_nv: ''
  }, { validator: [_fmError.bothEmptyValidator, _fmError.bothCapturedValidator, _fmError.FutureDateValidator] }),  });
```

Setting Data on UI:

```
let subject = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('SubjectPersonal')); 
this.subjectPersonalform.patchValue({ dob_info: { 
        dob:  subject['dob'] ,
        dob_nv: subject['dob_nv']
      },});
```

**Incoming Data from backend:**
[image]

HTML:

```
 <div class="form-group" formGroupName="dob_info">
          <span>Date of Birth</span>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control " bsDatepicker [bsConfig]="{containerClass:'theme-default'}"
              formControlName="dob">
            <select class="form-control col-sm-4" style="padding-right: 2px;padding-right: 2px;"
              formControlName="dob_nv">
              <option value="">Select</option>
              <option *ngFor="let dobNv of dobNvs" [value]="dobNv.CODE">{{ dobNv.CODE}}</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <small class='text-danger'
            *ngIf="subjectPersonalform.controls.dob_info.hasError('bothEmpty') && notSubmitted ">{{_fmError.getEmptyMessage()}}
          </small>
          <small class='text-danger'
            *ngIf="subjectPersonalform.controls.dob_info.hasError('bothCaptured') && notSubmitted ">{{_fmError.getBothCapturedMessage()}}
          </small>
          <small class='text-danger'
            *ngIf="subjectPersonalform.controls.dob_info.hasError('futureDate') && notSubmitted ">{{_fmError.getFutureDateMessage()}}
          </small>
        </div>
```

**Data displayed on UI is -> 11/17/2019**

Have found couple of issues reported on the same line, but solutions mentioned are not solving my issue.
Any help is highly appreciated..!..
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Resolved..!..Step1 (Angular to Node) - Used toISOString() in before passing date to NODE. Step 2 (@Node)-> new Date(.dob).toJSON().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ') , so ensured proper utc while saving. Step 3 (while fetching data to ui, added @ NODE- my sql connection setting-> added-> timezone: 'utc'.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because of [Timezone Offset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset). Add the timezone difference like:

```
let date = new Date("2019-11-17");
date = new Date(date.getTime() + date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)
```

Or replace `-` in your date string with `/`. 
Create date object like `new Date('2019/11/17')` instead of `new Date('2019-11-11)`

You can also fix this by setting the time with your date:

```
new Date('2019-11-17 00:00:00');
```

JavaScript date object behavior is complicated. Read this article to understand the reason for why the date is one day off http://www.sunzala.com/why-the-javascript-date-is-one-day-off/

Comment: Thanks for attending this issue. Unfortunately, issue still persists. have tried code**** let mydate = new Date('2019-11-18 00:00:00');// mydate = new Date(mydate.getTime() + mydate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)
    alert(mydate)***** then changed patch value to     dob:  mydate.  My alert gives "Mon Nov 18 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"  and "Sun Nov 17 2019 18:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" without and with timezone difference. Have tried formatting to '/' also. Though the first alert gives date as 18th Nov, on the date field on UI it shows 17 Nov.

Comment: pls check https://ngx-bootstrap-datepicker-fqnwus.stackblitz.io

Comment: The only cross-browser string formats are a variant of ISO 8601 and IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps (see [MDN's documentation for `Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2587345/215552)). Also, there's no such thing as a "TimezoneOffset".

Comment: yes..that option works for stackblitz code , but unfortunately not in application code